# How to make old custom ActionBar appear on new SDK?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-xml, android-appcompat, android-styles

I migrated my old Android (4.4 Kitkat) project from Eclipse to Android Studio.
When I run the app I have no ActionBar anymore!

Here is my main Activity class file:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.Open:
                intent = new Intent(this, Open.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

        case R.id.Email;
                intent = new Intent(this, Email.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.Compartir:
                intent = new Intent(this, Compartir.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.About:
                intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `styles.xml` file:

```
<resources>
        <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
            <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
        </style>

    <style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_expand</item>
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">"Lala"</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

that I call from manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

[image]

In the project I have `options.xml`, as you can see it creates the content of the Action Bar: 1 buttons + the option button that is a dropdown menu with 3 buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/Open"
        android:title="@string/option_open"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_open"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />    

    <item android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:title="@string/option_email"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_person"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/Compartir"
        android:title="@string/option_compartir"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/About"
        android:title="@string/option_about"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Anyway, if I build the app I get no ActionBar on my phone. I had it when I build the app with Eclipse ADT. I think the difference is the SDK old version that I used before. Then, how to make the ActionBar appears again with that custom theme?

Comment: Can you show how it was previously?

Comment: I have attached an image in the question. Can you see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to go back to Holo theme:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Can you tell me why I need to make this change? Can you provide more information?

Comment: You are somehow dependent on old styles, but I cannot tell why action bar won't show up with new styles in your case, because normally it should have. That means you have some logics, that interfere showing new action bar. Cannot provide even deeper information based on this much chunk of code, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: I tried to add `.DarkActionBar` but none is changed.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43469294/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.